# PHPFox caching?

Tags: php, webserver, cache, nginx

I run a big phpfox website and I currently have server setup as follows:

nginx (reverse proxy) --> Apache for dynamic content

are there other ways to cache content with phpfox?

I can't use memcache it's a shared environment.

Answer (score 2):

phpFox has its own caching system that...

You can disable the caching in phpFox by using the following code in your template files:

```
<?php
define('PHPFOX_NO_TEMPLATE_CACHE', true);
define('PHPFOX_NO_CSS_CACHE', true);
define('PHPFOX_LIVE_TEMPLATES', true);
define('PHPFOX_CACHE_SKIP_DB_STORE', true);
?>
```

You can also use your own caching on top using Nginx virtual host configuration file:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
expires 1y;
log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: I have had great results using local caching in nginx like this, not with PHPFox specifically but with a large site serving up static content.